# PHP same page pass php variable to page meta tag for Facebook mobile sharer

Tags: php, html, metadata

Good day guys,

I need some assistance. Is there a way in PHP to pass an PHP variable to the Meta tag on the same page?

Comment: show some code to check..

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what you mean but maybe this?

```
<?php
$author = "Jimmi";
?>

<meta name="author" content="<?php=$author;?>">
```